# RxJava 2 dispose resources in reverse order

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Basically, what I'm after is how to create resources 1,2,3,4, process results, and then dispose of 4,3,2,1 with the requirement that if there's an error creating resource 3, we only have to dispose of 2,1.

As an example, let's say we have this:

Observable1 reads lines from a file and does one emission per line.
For proper handling of the file resource the file should be opened at the beginning, and closed at the end.

Observable2 should accept the emissions from Observable1, and write them to another file. For the sake of simplicity let's say that we only need to add a comma at the end of each line. 
For the proper handling of another file resource, we should create the new file at the beginning and flush and close it at the end.

I guess it should look something like

```
observable1.flatMap ( line -> { doMagicHere(line+",") } )
    .subscribe ( line -> { System.out.println(line) },
     ex -> { ex.printStackTrace() }
     )
```

If an error occurs while opening file1, we should not create file2 (nor dispose it)
If an error occurs while processing the lines, file2 should be disposed first and only then, should file1 be disposed. (even if in this particular example it works either way)

I think I can create Observable1 with the Observable.using() operator, where we open the file in the first parameter, create the observable in the 2nd parameter and, finally, dispose (close) the file in the 3d parameter.

I am at a loss how to apply the "using" operator in the 2nd step, or if it is the right way to go about it.

Thanks for any solution or pointers (preferably in rxjava 2)

Comment: Use Observable.using() to do resource allocation & cleanup. (or Flowable, or Single... etc)

Answer (score 1):

For backward range i use this code

```
  Observable.range(0,10)
        .map { 10 - it }
        .subscribe {
            print(it)
            //emit 10,9,8,...,2,1
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start with `Observable.using()`. However, the first observable is:

```
Observable<Observable<String>> observable1;
```

By adding this indirection, you can handle the situation where the first resource fails to load.

```
interface FileWriter {
  void write(String line);
}
Observable<FileWriter> makeDestinationFile(String filename);
```

By introducing the `FileWriter` abstraction, you can then bind the second resource.

```
observable1.flatMap(
    lineSource -> 
      Observable.combineLatest( lineSource,
      makeDestinationFile(filename),
      ( line, writer ) -> writer.write( line + "," ) )
  .subscribe();
```

When `observable1` reaches completion, both observables will be completed, and the underlying resources released.

Comment: I misread part of the requirement. I will shortly edit the answer to address that.